# Allocate incomplete type on stack

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, types

I am working on wrapping a C++ library in C. The C++ library is a library for a database server. It uses a wrapper class for passing around serialized data. I can't use that class directly in C, so I defined a struct that can be used in C code like this:

In `include/c-wrapper/c-wrapper.h` (this is the wrapper that clients of my C wrapper are including)

```
extern "C" {
    typedef struct Hazelcast_Data_t Hazelcast_Data_t;

    Hazelcast_Data_t *stringToData(char *str);
    void freeData(Hazelcast_Data_t *d);
}
```

In `impl.pp`

```
extern "C" struct Hazelcast_Data_t {
    hazelcast::client::serialization::pimpl::Data data; // this is the C++ class
};

Hazelcast_Data_t *stringToData(char *str) {
     Data d = serializer.serialize(str);

     Hazelcast_Data_t *dataStruct = new Hazelcast_Data_t();
     dataStruct->data = d;

     return dataStruct;
}

...
```

Now this works, the client of my C library only sees `typedef struct Hazelcast_Data_t Hazelcast_Data_t;`. The problem is, that the aforementioned type cannot be allocated on the stack, like if I would like to provide an API like this:

```
// this is what I want to achieve, but Hazelcast_Data_t is an incomplete type
#include <include/c-wrapper/c-wrapper.h>

int main() {
    char *str = "BLA";
    Hazelcast_Data_t d;
    stringToData(str, &d);
}
```

The compiler will throw an error that Hazelcast_Data_t is an incomplete type. I would still like to provide an API that allows to pass a stack-allocated reference of `Hazelcast_Data_t` to the serialization function, but because `Hazelcast_Data_t` has a pointer to the C++ class, this seems pretty much impossible. Having the option to pass a stack allocated reference however would greatly simplify the code for the client of my C library (no need to free the `new`ed structure).

Is it somehow doable to redefine `Hazelcast_Data_t` type so that it can be used in C and still be allocated on the stack?

Comment: Does Hazelcast_Data_t really contain a pointer to the C++ class, or does it contain the actual C++ struct or class object?  If it's really only a pointer, then you shouldn't have many problems since the sizeof a pointer is well known even for incomplete types (i.e. its always 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system).  You might have to store the pointer as (void *) to make it easier for the C compiler to understand, but outside of that I don't see why it would be a problem.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Hazelcast_Data_t contains the actual data. I also thought I could use a void pointer, but I cannot cast `Hazelcast_Data_t data` to `void *` and I cannot take it's address because it's a local stack variable.

Comment: At person who voted to close: please help me to understand why it's not clear what is being asked in my question. I'm still pretty new to C/C++ programming and might have used the wrong terms to desribe my problem. Vote to close with reason "unclear" doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the hacks you're thinking of for doing this invoke undefined behaviour, since C will not call the C++ constructor for the contained object when the struct is created, and not call the C++ destructor when the struct goes out of scope. To make it work you need the struct to contain a buffer of the right size and new into that buffer in an init function, and call the destructor on that buffer when done. This means the code looks like this (assuming that nothing throws - in which case you need to add exception handling and translation...)

```
struct wrapper {
  char buffer[SIZE_OF_CXX_CLASS];
}

void wrapper_init() {
   new (buffer) Wrapped();
}

void wrapper_destroy() {
   ((Wrapper*)buffer)->~Wrapper();
}

{
  struct wrapper wrapped;
  wrapper_init(&wrapped);
  // ... use it ...
  wrapper_destroy(&wrapped);
}
```

If you forget to call `wrapper_init` everything goes into undefined behvaiour land. If you forget to call `wrapper_destroy` I think you get UB too.

But since this forces your caller to call the init and destroy functions there's very little gain over using a pointer. I'd go so far as to claim that the use of a struct rather than a pointer suggests to API users that initialisation should be trivial, and destruction unnecessary. I.e. as an API user I'd expect to be able to do

```
 {
   struct wrapper wrapped = WRAPPER_INIT; //Trivial initialisaton macro
   // .. use it ..
   // No need to do anything it is a trivial object.
 }
```

In the cases where this is not possible (like yours) I'd stick with the usual *allocate it on the heap* idiom

```
{
   struct wrapper* wrapped = wrapper_create();
   // ... use it ...
   wrapper_destroy(wrapped);
}
```

Comment: I agree with you after all. I just thought I can avoid many heap allocations, as the library is used for interacting with a database, i can imagine there are many calls to create/destroy which create a lot of small memory allocating/freeing calls. But in the end, I also want the API to be safe and usable.

Comment: If you find allocations of these objects to be a bottleneck later, you can optimize most of that cost away by using a different allocation scheme, like using a pool, inside `wrapper_create`.

Comment: Very good insight, I agree. I will build the simple version now and see if it actually creates a problem or not. Thanks a lot Michael, sometimes working on a project alone makes it a bit hard to not get stuck on a certain idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a definition of the struct in your header file such so that clients know how much space to allocate on the stack.  But that becomes tricky when the underlying representation in a C++ class which can't be exposed by the `extern "C"`.

The solution is a pointer to the C++ class rather than the actual class.  As pointers are the same size this will work in the C client, even when it has no knowledge of C++.

Thus in the header

```
typedef struct Hazelcast_Data_t {
       void *data
} Hazelcast_Data_t
```

And in the C++ file you can use `static_cast` to access the C++ class via this pointer.

Comment: This is no different from passing around pointers to the original incomplete type.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper struct that simply contains an array large and aligned enough to contain your C++ type. Placement-new your C++ type in it.

You will probably have to build a small C++ executable that would generate a C header file with SIZEOF_HAZELCAST_T and ALIGNOF_HAZELCAST_T appropriately defined.

Comment: I'm not sure about this approach, not even if I want to do it, but could you explain a bit more about `ou will probably have to build a small C++ executable that would generate a C header file with SIZEOF_HAZELCAST_T and ALIGNOF_HAZELCAST_T appropriately defined.` How would such an executable look like? The class per see looks relatively easy, but I dont really know how to get "the size" of it https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/blob/master/hazelcast/include/hazelcast/client/serialization/pimpl/Data.h

Comment: But in any case, as Michael Anderson pointed out, I need a destroy function, otherwise the desructor of the CPP class is never called.

Comment: Well if your class needs a destructor, you may just as well forget about this whole idea because the users will have to call a cleanup function one way or another.

Comment: I had a look at the current implementation of the `Data` class, it doesn't seem to have a destructor right now, but I suspect it could get one in future versions of the C++ client. I consider this 3rd party code which I cannot change, therefore it would be too risky to rely on that. Thanks a lot for your insights nontheless.